# Oracle SQL : Data won't get inserted into super table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to create two classes, Persons and Customers. Customers being the subclass of Persons. When I try to insert values into Customers table, although I can see the value inserted in the customers table, I don't understand why it wouldn't get inserted into Persons table also as it is a superclass of customers. Is there a way I can insert into subclass through superclass or vice versa? Here is my code

```
CREATE TYPE PersonType AS OBJECT (
 PID VARCHAR2(5),
 Name VARCHAR2(30),
 Address VARCHAR2(35),
 age NUMBER(3)
 ) NOT FINAL;
/
CREATE TABLE Person of PersonType;
/
 CREATE TYPE CustomerType UNDER PersonType (
 CID VARCHAR2(20));
/
CREATE TABLE Customer of CustomerType;
/
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(CustomerType('P2','Andy','Poland',21,'SS','C9'));
/
SELECT * FROM Person;
```

Comment: try by using commit after insert statement (before SELECT statement)

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a row in an object table, it only goes in that table. Even if it's a subtype.

If you want the data in both `person` and `customer`, you need two inserts. But then you're duplicating the customer attributes!

When you have a type hierarchy, you can create an object table on the parent object. And insert subtypes into that. You only need to create a separate customer table if you want to only insert `CustomerType` objects into it.

If you insert all objects in the `person` table, you can pull out rows of a specific subtype with the `is of (<objecttype>)'` condition:

```
CREATE TYPE PersonType AS OBJECT (
 PID VARCHAR2(5),
 Name VARCHAR2(30),
 Address VARCHAR2(35),
 age NUMBER(3)
 ) NOT FINAL;
/
CREATE TYPE CustomerType UNDER PersonType (
 CID VARCHAR2(20));
/

INSERT INTO Person VALUES(CustomerType('P2','Andy','Poland',21,'SS'));
INSERT INTO Person VALUES(PersonType('P3','Chris','Poland',21));

select * from person p;

PID   NAME    ADDRESS   AGE   
P2    Andy    Poland         21 
P3    Chris   Poland         21 

select * from person p
where  value ( p ) is of ( CustomerType );

PID   NAME   ADDRESS   AGE   
P2    Andy   Poland         21
```

But to be honest, you're better off storing the data using regular relational tables:

```
create table person (
 pid     varchar2(5) 
   primary key,
 name    varchar2(30),
 address varchar2(35),
 age     number(3)
);
create table customer (
 pid 
   references person ( pid ) 
   not null,
 cid varchar2(20)
);
```